# how can i change the repeater's label value from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, repeater, asprepeater

i have the following code Default.aspx

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" >

 <ItemTemplate>


  <asp:Label ID="lbllat" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LAT")%>'></asp:Label>

  <asp:Label ID="lbllon" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LON")%>'></asp:Label>

  <asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server"></asp:Label>

  </ItemTemplate>

   </asp:Repeater>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("fetch_data)",
                 new SqlParameter("@Field", "*"),
                 new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "gps_data"));


            rpt.DataSource = ds;
            rpt.DataBind();


     for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            String address = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LAT"].ToString() + "," + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LON"].ToString() + "&sensor=false";
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(address);
            String formatted_address = Regex.Match(json, @"(?s)""formatted_address""\s*:\s*""(.+?)""").Groups[1].Value;

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
            {
                Label lab = item.FindControl("lbladdress") as Label;
                lab.Text = formatted_address.ToString();
            }
        }
```

From above code i am able to fetch latitude and longitude but after that when i fetch the address from latitude and longitude then it will fetch all the address of different latitude and longitude but it is set address of last latitude and longitude address.

so i am seeing the same address on all records instead of different addresses.

how can i set address according to their latitude and longitude .?

Comment: that's because you have it coded to do exactly that every time in the foreach loop you are overwriting the previous value.. you would need to do something like this `Label lab = new Label()` assign it a Id , then assign it's perspective text.. etc.... use the debugger and step through the code and you will see exactly what's going on here..

Comment: i had also tried this `Label lab = new Label()`  but still same address in all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your code in this way:

**Before**

```
String address = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LAT"].ToString() + "," + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LON"].ToString() + "&sensor=false";

foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
{
    Label lab = item.FindControl("lbladdress") as Label;
    lab.Text = formatted_address.ToString();
}
```

**After**

```
String address = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LAT"].ToString() + "," + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LON"].ToString() + "&sensor=false";

RepeaterItem item = rpt.Items[i];
Label lab = item.FindControl("lbladdress") as Label;
lab.Text = formatted_address.ToString();
```